# Plotting the area of an object in grayscale against its intensity level in the grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, image-segmentation

Basically what I am trying to produce is the histogram of the image at varying grayscale intensities showing me the area of the connected components in the image.

Let me explain further, I plan on finding the areas of all the connected components of the image at **varying** threshold levels. Then combine them all in a graphical way and show them plotted against the intensity level of a grayscale image i.e. `0 - 255`.

I hope my code will explain what I am trying to do.

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('W1\Writer1_01_02.jpg'));

for k = 1:-0.01:0.1
     bw_normal = im2bw(img, k);
     bw = imcomplement(bw_normal);
     [label,n] = bwlabel(bw);
     stats = regionprops(label,img, {'Area', 'Centroid'});
      plot([stats.Area],k,'o');
      axis([0 1000 0.1 1])

     hold on;
     
 end
```

As you can tell I used a for loop to produce a the varying threshold level, calculate the areas of the CC and plot them against the selected threshold level. This is what it produces:

[image]

this is not what I want. I am trying to replicate this result. It does not have to look exactle like this but anything closely similar would do

[image]

I then found out that I can find the properties of CC from the grayscale image directly using `STATS = regionprops(..., I, properties)`

So I wrote this:

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('W1\Writer1_01_02.jpg'));

for k = 1:-0.01:0.1
     bw_normal = im2bw(img, k);
     bw = imcomplement(bw_normal);
     [label,n] = bwlabel(bw);
     stats = regionprops(label,img, {'Area', 'Centroid'});
%       plot([stats.Area],k,'o');
%       axis([0 1000 0.1 1])
      imshow(img);
     hold on;
     for j = 1:numel(stats)
         text(stats(j).Centroid(1),stats(j).Centroid(2), ...
        sprintf('%2.1f', stats(j).Area), ...
        'EdgeColor','b','Color','r');
     end
     
 end
```

This produced the following:

[image]

So now I have found the areas of the connected components in grayscale. How do I plot them to show as my desired output (the blue one I showed above)?

thank you for reading

Comment: can you make your raw data available.  If I am going to look at code to accomplish something, having actual inputs to work with can assure higher quality output.

Comment: Thank you. No specific data is required. Any text image would do. Like the image i showed in the end.

Comment: I think for each greyscale level you need to extract a list of all the `Area` values and construct a histogram out of them (using consistent bin values). Each row in that "width map" would be a histogram for an individual threshold level.

Comment: @nkjt Can you add an answer containing the code to how this would be accomplished. What you said appears to produce my desired result but I do not know how to plot a histogram in the way you explained. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your existing code:

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('W1\Writer1_01_02.jpg'));
k = 1:-0.01:0.1;
bins = 1:100 % change depending on your image

% preallocate output - this will be filled with histograms
histout = zeros(length(k),length(bins); 

for m = 1:length(k); 
     bw_normal = im2bw(img, k(m));
     bw = imcomplement(bw_normal);
     [label,n] = bwlabel(bw);
     stats = regionprops(label,img, {'Area'});
     A = cell2mat(struct2cell(stats));
     histout(m,:) = hist(A,bins);
end
```

I changed the output of `regionprops` to just `Area` because it simplifies conversion of the output struct into something that can be read by `hist`.  Changing from looping through `k` to predefining a vector `k` and using `k(m)` in the loop just makes indexing into `histout` a little more straight forward.

You can display with `imagesc` and then correct the tick labelling:

```
imagesc(histout)
colormap('jet')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',bins(get(gca,'XTick')));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',k(get(gca,'YTick')));
xlabel('Area')
ylabel('Threshold')
```